# Найти в строке максимум и прибавить к нему значение из другого столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```
myData ={'A1':[1,3,-10,4,5],
     'A2':[2,1,4,2,5],
     'A3':[3,4,2,1,3],
     'DD':[10,20,30,10,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)

#    A1 A2  A3  DD
# 0  1  2   3   10
# 1  3  1   4   20
# 2 -10 4   2   30
# 3  4  2   1   10
# 4  5  5   3   20
```

Необходимо в каждой строке столбцов `A1`, `A2`, `A3` найти первый максимум и прибавить к нему значение из столбца `DD`.

Желаемый результат:

```
#    A1 A2  A3  DD
# 0  1  2   13  10
# 1  3  1   24  20
# 2 -10 34  2   30
# 3  14 2   1   10
# 4  25 5   3   20
```

Как это сделать средствами Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

векторизированный вариант решения:

```
In [199]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [200]: cols = ["A1", "A2", "A3"]

In [201]: idx_max = df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)

In [202]: idx_max
Out[202]:
0    A3
1    A3
2    A2
3    A1
4    A1
dtype: object

In [203]: df.loc[:, cols] += \
              csr_matrix((df["DD"], (idx_max.index, df.columns.get_indexer(idx_max)))).A
```

результат:

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]:
   A1  A2  A3  DD
0   1   2  13  10
1   3   1  24  20
2 -10  34   2  30
3  14   2   1  10
4  25   5   3  20
```

Answer (score 2):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   A1  A2  A3  DD
0   1   2   3  10
1   3   1   4  20
2 -10   4   2  30
3   4   2   1  10
4   5   5   3  20
```

Решение:

```
cols = ["A1", "A2", "A3"]

for row, col in df[cols].idxmax(axis=1).iteritems():
     df.loc[row, col] += df.at[row, "DD"]
```

Результат:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
   A1  A2  A3  DD
0   1   2  13  10
1   3   1  24  20
2 -10  34   2  30
3  14   2   1  10
4  25   5   3  20
```

Comment: Кажется, что в ряду 0 в колонке А3 должно быть 13.

Comment: Там вроде бы требуется максимум по строкам.

Comment: @becouse, похоже на то. Исправил ответ...

Comment: Да, мне по строкам нужно пробежать. В каждой строке определяем максимум в нескольких колонках.

Comment: MaxU, Спасибо большое!